# Utility App - Done button no longer worked since I embedded both views in navigation controllers

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, transition, navigationcontroller

OK so I've got a two page/view app using the Utility Template and to solve layout problems with the Info & Navigation Bars I have embedded the mainviewcontroller and the flipsideviewcontroller in a Navigation Controller each.

The Info Button works fine in the Main View but the 'Done' button doesn't work in the Flip View, it doesn't dismiss the view.

I know little about coding and like to use the storyboards (just where possible) to define and sort stuff out but if this isn't solvable that way please tell me what I need to do to my code/add to my code.

Let me know what code out of the following you need to see and I'll update this question:

MainViewController h
MainViewController m
FlipsideViewController h
FlipsideViewController m

Answer (score 0):

Click on the segue arrow in your storyboard, and then give it an identifier in the attributes inspector. Set that identifier in your code.